# Can alkali-doped exohedral fullerene molecules show superconducivity?

Tags: physical-chemistry, conductivity, carbon-allotropes, alkali-metals

Alkali doped fullerenes are one of the few organic materials that show superconductivity. However, when attaching a new molecular system to a fullerene doped with an alkali metal, will it still show superconductivity?

Comment: Attaching what system? Most of stuff you'd attach would react with an alkali metal.

Comment: These things are probably best formulated [M+]3 [C60]3- , at least according to Housecroft and Sharpe. There is also says the K, Rb and Cs salts are superconducting at low T, but not the Na case. So it seems perfectly reasonable to think about what happens if you add something onto the fullerene - though my guess is that as this is addition rather than substitution you are too radically changing the electronic structure to see the same effect. Fullerenes are not benzene.

Comment: Superconductivity is a tricky thing, you can't expect to predict it with qualitative considerations.